# Adding A to appendix: Missing-Number-Error

Tags: numbering, amsmath

I want to add "A" to equations in my appendix (and not to other chapters). At several places here, I found the solution to be `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}`. I tried that, However I get **Missing number, treated as zero** when I try that in my code (and also in the following MWE).

What's going on?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\appendix
\section{Bar}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
1+1=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no `chapter` counter in `article`. You have to use `section`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\value` expects a counter register, i.e. it tries to use `\c@chapter` which is not available in `article` class.

Replace `chapter` with `section` then.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\appendix
\section{Bar}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
1+1=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```